# "child exited with status 13" when trying to run fastcgi examples with lighttpd

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd

I have compiled fastcgi c-api examples: http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/
They work fine when I execute them manually in the command line (by typing ./echo for example) but I have some troubles when I try to make it work with lighttpd.

```
"/echo.fcgi" => (
                  "localhost" => (
                          "socket" => "/tmp/echo.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/Users/onur/Downloads/fcgi-2.4.0/examples/tiny",
                          "check-local" => "disable"
                  ),
          )
```

---

```
new-host:examples onur$ ls -la echo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 _www  _www  3322 Aug  4 21:21 echo
```

What am I missing? What are the specificities of the execution of a binary with fastcgi in lighttpd?

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't this:

```
 "bin-path" => "/Users/onur/Downloads/fcgi-2.4.0/examples/tiny",
```

be something like this, instead?

```
 "bin-path" => "/Users/onur/Downloads/fcgi-2.4.0/examples/echo",
```

you are trying to run **echo** and not **tiny**, aren't you?